# DimpleJS tooltip's dotted line not drawn towards the X-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dimple.js

The tooltip that's shown when a mouse is hovered over a data point in chart rendered by DimpleJS, in the case of the line towards the X axis is going in the reverse direction.

Please check this fiddle to see the behavior:
[JSFIDDLE CODE DEMO URL](http://jsfiddle.net/S6FLv/483/)

Steps -
1. Hover over any data point. example, the green one corresponding to this:

```
 {'Date': '09-03-2013', 'Views': 'c', 'Owner':'Gamma','Rating':'**'}
```

In the above case, just as we hover, two dotted lines are created, one towards the X-axis and the other towards the Y-axis. While the one towards the Y-axis goes and meets the axis line as expected, the dotted line for the X-axis actually is drawn towards the top and not towards the bottom to meet the X-axis line.

No amount of code change on that fiddle is working for me. Tried with Chrome and firefox, same behavior.

Note: That is not my fiddle code, but mine is close to it and I'm seeing that same behavior.

Why is the dotted line not going towards the X-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using version 1.1.1 of dimple.js? When I updated to the latest 2.2.0 then it started to work properly.

```
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/y1Lvq4bq/